# AutoMapper version 5.0.0-beta-1 - Created Mapper shows exceptions

Tags: automapper

I updated automapper package today and it got updated to 5.0.0-beta and i immediately got few build errors. Going through the latest changes in their [wiki  page](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki) i found that CreateMap is deprecated. So i followed their instruction and here is my code below.

[image]

The created mapper shows these exception about which i have no clue. I am not able to continue further. Should i do something extra with this new version of AutoMapper? Any help would be greatly appreciated. My POCO classes are just regular ones with int and strings.

Comment: Those are exceptions thrown from static member access, only during debugging. What's the exception that you're actually seeing thrown?

Comment: I am sorry for wasting your time Jimmy. I was getting an exception first and while debugging i saw the above error and thought this could be a reason. I never went beyond this breakpoint to check if its actually working. Now that  i ran the code beyond breakpoint i see it is working fine. I cant even remember about the first exception and why i started debugging. :( Go ahead and downvote the question as Not useful. It is not allowing me to do it myself. Thank you so much for your time. AutoMapper is awesome.

Comment: Lol no worries man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a new Mapper instance now:

```
var mapper = new Mapper(config);
builder.RegisterInstance(mapper).As<IMapper>();
```

Or, if you prefer the old static way, just use Mapper.Initialize().